# Find $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\sin(x^3y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> Find $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}  \frac{\sin(x^3y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$

I tried multiplying $x^3y^3$ the nominator and denominator, didn't work.

I tried the polar way too, $x = r \cos\phi$, $y=r \sin\phi$,$x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ too. which gives me $\frac{"0"}{"0"}$

I tried proving that this limit doesn't exist but wolfram shows that its limit is zero.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to approach this?

Comment: Move along $y=kx$ may be

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici You want me to show that this limit doesn't exist with that way? for example $k = 1 , k = 2$

Comment: If the limit exists, it is the same "from all directions". After having proven that the limit exists, one should take a convenient curve along which the limit is simple to take.

Comment: Not at all ! It is just a suggestion. Use later $\sin(z)\approx z$

Comment: Maybe first thing you can say is that $sin(x^3y^2) \approx x^3y^2$. Then there is a quotient of a 5th order polynomial by a 4th order polynomial. Intuitively this tends to 0. But i'm note sure it's rigorous!

Comment: @JulienRoussillon. To me, it is a good way. Nice to meet you here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switching to polar is a good idea and gives
$$\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{\sin\left(r^5 \cos^3t\sin^2t \right)}{r^4}$$
You probably know that $\sin(a)/a$ tends to 1 for $a \to 0$; so:
$$\begin{array}{cc}
\displaystyle \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{\sin\left(r^5 \cos^3t\sin^2t \right)}{r^4} & \displaystyle
= \lim_{r \to 0} \left( \frac{\sin\left(r^5 \cos^3t\sin^2t \right)}{r^5 \cos^3t\sin^2t}(r \cos^3t\sin^2t) \right) \\ \\
& \displaystyle 
= \underbrace{\lim_{r \to 0}  \frac{\sin\left(r^5 \cos^3t\sin^2t \right)}{r^5 \cos^3t\sin^2t}}_{\to 1} \underbrace{\lim_{r \to 0}  \left( r \cos^3t\sin^2t \right)}_{\to \ldots} 
\end{array}$$
Can you take it from here?

---

Alternatively:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{\sin(x^3y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}
=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{\sin(x^3y^2)}{x^3y^2}\frac{x^3y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}
=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^3y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} = \cdots$$
And use $x^2+y^2 \ge 2xy$.

Comment: After u wrote alternatively the nominator is zero and deniminator $\rightarrow 0$? Meaning it is zero?

Comment: Both tend to 0, but that doesn't mean the limit is 0. With the last hint:
$$\left| \frac{x^3y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \right| \le \left| \frac{x^3y^2}{(2xy)^2} \right| = \ldots \to \ldots$$

Comment: I see, but now it goes to $\frac{1}{4x} , x \rightarrow 0$ and it is $∞$.

Comment: Are you sure? You should end up with an $x$ in the numerator...!

Comment: oh right. and now I need to apply sandwich.

Comment: And you're done! You can verify the answer with the 'polar way'.

Comment: Yes, now I'm checking your polar way. I'll remember the $x^2+y^2 \ge 2xy$

Comment: Done, this is perfect! Thank you  very much!!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

You can use $|\sin t| \le |t|$ and AM-GM inequality:
$$
\left|\frac{\sin(x^3 y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right|\le \left|\frac{x^3y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right|\le \left|\frac{x^3y^2}{(2xy)^2}\right|=\frac{1}{4}|x|
$$
and apply sandwich theorem.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\sin(x^3y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=\frac{x^3y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\frac{\sin(x^3y^2)}{x^3y^2}$$

The second factor above tends to $\;1\;$ and as for the first one: with polar coordinates:
$$\frac{x^3y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\rightarrow r\cos^3\theta\sin^2\theta\xrightarrow[r\to0]{}0$$

Thus the whole thing tends to zero

Comment: This is the fastest and easiest solution here. Thanks Joan!

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS  Aby time, Ilan.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

As I wrote in comments, move along $y=kx$. Then $$ A=\frac{\sin(x^3y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=\frac{\sin \left(k^2 x^5\right)}{\left(k^2+1\right)^2 x^4}$$ Now, for small $z$, $\sin(z]\approx z$ So $$A \approx \frac{k^2 x^5}{\left(k^2+1\right)^2 x^4}=\frac{k^2 x}{\left(k^2+1\right)^2 }$$